# how to auto height ,width of div z-indexed content

Tags: html, css, z-index

i am trying to auto height width of parent div in which there are 3 images stacked one on the other but the parent is not taking the height and width of the content even when div and the last image are on same z-index;
here is a illustration of what is happening and what i would like 
i cannot use static values as it is needed to be responsive
[here is the illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q8d1.jpg)

here is my code :

```css
.image_holder {
        margin-top: 5em;
      
        overflow: visible;
        background-color: red;
     display:block;
       z-index: -12;
        position:relative;
         border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color:red;
    }

.image_preview_parent {
    position: absolute;
}


/*----------layers start---------*/
.layer_Back {
    z-index: -12;
}

.layer_Camera {
    z-index: -11;
}

.layer_Logo {
    z-index: -10;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_holder">
  <img class="image_preview_parent layer_Logo" src="https://www.transparencyatwork.org/assets/fallback/employers/logo/thumb_default-9fbd6d06cb43649ddc8bfd34eb4b1192396a73474ce3c27cb5830b9edf86ae23.png" />
 <img class="image_preview_parent layer_Camera" src="https://freepngimg.com/thumb/sunglasses/14-2-sunglasses-transparent-thumb.png" />
                            <img class="image_preview_parent layer_Back" src="https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/673084cc885831461ab2cdd1151ad577cda6a49a/92a4d/static/images/favicon.png" />
  </div>
```

Comment: can you share live example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make all the images `position:absolute` because you will remove all of them from the flow thus there is no in-flow content that will define the height of the container. keep at least one `position:relative`. You can also change the container to `inline-block` to make the width fit the content.

As a side note, `z-index` has nothing to do here, so whataver the values you will use it will only affect the stack order and not height or width:

```css
.image_holder {
  margin-top: 5em;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;/*this is the parent element so any value should be enough, you don't need to make it lower that the child */
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: red;
  display:inline-block; /*to fit the width*/
}

.image_preview_parent {
  position:relative;
}
.image_preview_parent:not(:first-child) {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}


/*----------layers start---------*/

.layer_Back {
  z-index: -2;
}

.layer_Camera {
  z-index: -1;
}

.layer_Logo {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_holder">
  <img class="image_preview_parent layer_Logo" src="https://www.transparencyatwork.org/assets/fallback/employers/logo/thumb_default-9fbd6d06cb43649ddc8bfd34eb4b1192396a73474ce3c27cb5830b9edf86ae23.png" />
  <img class="image_preview_parent layer_Camera" src="https://freepngimg.com/thumb/sunglasses/14-2-sunglasses-transparent-thumb.png" />
  <img class="image_preview_parent layer_Back" src="https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/673084cc885831461ab2cdd1151ad577cda6a49a/92a4d/static/images/favicon.png" />
</div>
```